# ¿Cómo representar la Fórmula del amor en Python?

Tags: python, matemáticas

Con el fin de celebrar este 14 de Febrero sería bueno saber como un informático puede representar la fórmula del amor.

Lo primero es indicar que esta es la fórmula:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si despejamos la [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]  nos quedarán las siguientes soluciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la tarea es representarla en Python.

Comment: Podrías indicar que has sacado la idea de http://pybonacci.org/2016/02/14/formula-para-el-amor/

Comment: No he sacado la idea.. lo copie de ahi. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La representación sería utilizando `numpy` y `matplotlib` de esta forma:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-1,1,50)
y1 = np.sqrt(x * x) + np.sqrt(1 - x * x)
y2 = np.sqrt(x * x) - np.sqrt(1 - x * x)
plt.plot(x, y1, c='r', lw = 3)
plt.plot(x, y2, c='r', lw = 3)
plt.show()
```

y el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡ Feliz día de San Valentín !

Nota: Idea copiada literalmente de [aquí](http://pybonacci.org/2016/02/14/formula-para-el-amor/).